# JsonInclude custom filter with Spotbugs error EQ_CHECK_FOR_OPERAND_NOT_COMPATIBLE_WITH_THIS

Tags: jackson, spotbugs

I have a `Car` class and a custom `JsonInclude` filter class `IgnoreTrueFilter`, the goal is to only serialize `isNew` property when its value is false:

```java
public class Car {
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = IgnoreTrueFilter.class)
  private boolean isNew = true;
}

public static class IgnoreTrueFilter {
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object value) {
    if (!(value instanceof Boolean)) {
      return true;
    }
    return Boolean.TRUE.equals(value);
  }
}
```

This works fine functionally, but Spotbugs is complaining:

```
$IgnoreTrueFilter.equals(Object) checks for operand being a Boolean EQ_CHECK_FOR_OPERAND_NOT_COMPATIBLE_WITH_THIS
```

It looks like Spotbugs is expecting the overriden `equals` method to check for a IgnoreTrueFilter instance instead of Boolean. But I'm just following `JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM`'s guidance:

```
* Filter object's equals() method is called with value
* to serialize; if it returns true value is excluded
* (that is, filtered out); if false value is included.
```

Any idea how to get around this error?